# Yii One relation for multiple tables

Tags: php, yii

I am trying to write a customized relation that uses multiple tables, and this relation neeeds to join to the other tables by using a key from the first table.

Each table has the same columns.

So, let the story begin:

I am developing a online strategy based game. (PBBG - Persistant Browser Based Game)

I had a big table (30.000.000 rows) and I have split that table in 100 smaller tables (300.000 rows in each table).

The action happens within villages.

Details about the villages are stored within the `village` table.

Each village is situated within a continent, so there is a `k` number that gives me the continent that the village belongs to.

The village table has the following columns:

id - p.k.
x - x position on map
y - y position on map
k - f.k. continent id
name
user_id f.k.
points

I have 100 continents, that's why i have 100 new smaller tables.

I also have a table where I store the details for all the buildings.

The building details were stored within the `village_building` table.

So, from the original table `village_building` i now have `village_building_k1`, `village_building_k2`, ..., `village_building_k100`.

A `village_building_k...` table has the following columns:

id - p.k.
village_id - f.k.
building_id - f.k.

Now, I am trying to write a relation that jumps from model `village` to model `village_building_kX` where `X` should change when needed.

If I could use the `k` value from model `village`, that would give me the name of the table that i need to join.

If k = 2, the i need to jump from `village` to `village_building_k2` using a concat

```
public function tableName() {
        return 'village_building_k' . self::$k;
    }

public function relations() {
        return array(
            'relation_village_building' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'VillageBuildingKXSlaveM', 'village_id'),
        );
    }
```

`$model_village->relation_village_building->building_id`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to add some shared databases. Due to your big database you can't manage it by your framework. Just try shared database for manage databases. Also you can try mysql cluster for manage database [Follow this link](http://www.mysql.com/products/cluster/) and
[this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shard_%28database_architecture%29) This may be helpful for you. Remember one frameworks are some set of functions so that you can to manipulate your function with your codes and supporting environment like databases and etc.

Answer (score 5):

Are you sure, that you need to solve this problem on framework level? I suggest to use here something like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shard_(database_architecture)

Answer (score 2):

Actually you can try to pass db name from some global parameters, for example from session.

```
public function tableName()
{
   return 'village_building_k' . Yii::app()->session['table'];
}
```

Problem is to save session for your gamer long time. If you'll get alot of users, it will become a problem.

If you have few tables with same structure, probably your database architecture is wrong. If it was sharding, you need to change AR for this.

Main problem in yii and sharding is that AR in __construct() calls getMetaData() to get table schema, so you need table name in that level.

Search on forums for solutions, i personally didn't found good article on english. Here is article about horizontal sharding realisation with Yii and Redis [here](http://habrahabr.ru/post/129780/). It's on Russian, but you can watch atleast some code.

And 30.000.000 table is ok, if you'll work right way with it, even in mysql.

Comment: 30 mils and rising due to extensions; it will go up to 50 mils

Comment: It's fine. You dont have big data in this table, so you can index it and it will be fast. Also look at partitioning, what you did is actually partitioning, not sharding. This feature exist in mysql(or what you use). Just make 100 partitions in your table for all your continents. Selects in range of 1 or 2 partitions will be very fast, but avoid selects from alot of partitions. After creating indexes test speed of selects, some of them can slow down you. Avoid joins, GROUP BY,alot of OR, LIKE operators maybe some more.

Comment: Also you'll need to change AR to DAO, its way faster and less memory consuming. If sticked with AR - rewrite SELECT COUNT(*) query, or set totalItemCount for dataProvider (with explain for full table for example). Avoid bulk inserts/deletes with indexes. With this you should be fine, my DB grown up already to 200 mil, and it's ok.

Comment: I have different situation, just tested select for december last year, select with limit took 0.0630, count ~ same. 1.2mil results.

Comment: Yeah, have had 300M+ rows in mysql, and it's all good. I'd look into just keeping that one table, and heavy caching where possible.